# Parallel processing in Python à la Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a way of doing parallel processing in Python using concepts similar to those of Apple's [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_central_dispatch)?  Grand Central Dispatch looks, from the outset, like a nice way of handling parallel processing.

If Python does not have a mostly equivalent module, what are the fundamental concepts behind Grand Central Dispatch that could usefully be implemented in Python?

I don't know much about Grand Central Dispatch, hence this question: I would love to know **whether Grand Central Dispatch uses paradigms that (1) are not yet available in Python, and/or (2) could be implemented in Python**.

Comment: See `multiprocessing` http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @AustinMarshall: are you implying that `multiprocessing` essentially includes all the core concepts of Grand Central Dispatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not have an equivalent module, though twisted uses many of the same basic concepts (async APIs, callback-based).  The Python multiprocessing module actually uses sub-processes rather than threads and is not particularly equivalent either.  The best approach would probably be one similar to that taken by MacRuby, which is to create wrappers for the GCD APIs and use those.  Unlike Python, of course, MacRuby was also designed not to have a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) and this will reduce the effectiveness of multi-threading in Python as various interpret threads hit the GIL at different times.  Not much to do about that other than redesign the language, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for this discussion.  Would it make sense to implement some core concepts of GCD through subprocesses?  or is it somewhat already done in either the `multiprocessing` or the `concurrent.future` modules?

Comment: One of the core concepts of GCD is that it is light-weight and your blocks / callbacks run in the same address space, so no, I don't think it would make sense to do that.  I think API wrappers would still make the most sense.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you implying that there is no concept from Grand Central Dispatch (Sources, Groups,…) that Python does not have in some form or the other (for instance in its `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures` modules)?

Comment: I'm not saying there are _no_ concepts shared between GCD and the ever-expanding world that is Python, I'm sure there are, but GCD also brings a certain uniformity of design to its approach to handling concurrency and I don't think "mixing and matching" would deliver the results you want, particularly if you expect all the various subsystems to play nicely (thread-safely) with one another.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem here is the compiler and OS part of GCD. In order to have GCD running, you need the compiler to understand Blocks. You could create something that works similarly when programming, but it wouldn't have the same performance at all. With GCD you can create and enqueue thousands of Blocks, and still, there will only be 2 or 4 threads executing this blocks. If you implement the high level functionality of Blocks without the compiler accepting them, the only way I see is to use threads for "simulating" Blocks. Then, using thousands of threads in a system with 2 to 4 CPU cores, would be an spectacular performance mess, due to context switching, and memory use.

Not only you need the proper compiler extension to support GCD, but also you need a proper OS extension to manage the GCD queues where Blocks are enqueued. You need the OS to behave in a way that it controls how many threads are executing, and when and how many of them to activate when CPU cores are available, for the program using GCD. With GCD, threads and queues are independent. The threads just grab Blocks from queues (light data structures), but from any of those. So it doesn't matter how many blocks are there, because they are only pieces of code and pointers stored somewhere in the main memory.

You simply can't implement all this low level features from python. And only implementing the high level "GCD way of programming", you are going to make veeeery slow programs, or maybe even impossible to execute in a personal computer.

So first, for instance Cython could support GCD, and the OS that you want to use too. Linux has an implementation called libdispatch, available for Debian. But it only implements the compiler portion, so the program starts as many threads as cores on the system minus one. So I think it is still not a good option. Someone should add Linux OS support for GCD, maybe as a kernel module.

Nothing to say about Windows. I really don't know.

So the first natural step, should be to add and test support of CGD in Cython, for Mac OS. From there, you could do a native Python library that internally uses de Cython GCD library, to offer blocks and queues to normal python programmers.

Anoder option could be the CPython project to embrace this, and the Python project to add blocks and queues as a native feature of python. That would be amazing XD